# How do I set the sender on a NSMenuItem's action?

Tags: cocoa, nsmenuitem, target-action

The Apple documentation says that the sender passed to the NSMenuItem's action can be set to some custom object, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Is there a method I'm not seeing someplace in the documentation?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm not sure what piece of documentation you're referring to (a link would help).

You can use the `-setRepresentedObject:` method of `NSMenuItem` to associate an arbitrary object with a menu item:

```
//assume "item" is an NSMenuItem object:

NSString* someObj = @"Some Arbitrary Object";

[item setRepresentedObject:someObj];
[item setAction:@selector(doSomething:)];
```

Then when the menu item sends its action message you can obtain the object:

```
- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"The menu item's object is %@",[sender representedObject]);
}
```

Comment: I can't remember off the top of my head what documentation it was, but I did end up figuring this out.

Comment: Silly question :  Why use the representedObject when we can just use the NSMenuItem title ?

Comment: You shouldn't use titles because they can be localized etc. It's much better to use the `-representedObject` as it's designed to store arbitrary data.