# Cocoa - How to pass a parameter with NSMenuItem's action?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am creating a menu programmatically:

```
+ (void)refreshStatusMenu {
    for (NSDictionary *dict in kbMsgSet) {
        NSString *msj = [dict objectForKey:@"msj"];
        NSString *mid = [dict objectForKey:@"mid"]; // <- this would be http://www.blah.com 

        msg_item = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", msj] action:@selector(goToURL:mid:) keyEquivalent:@""];

        [msg_item setTarget:[self class]];
        [sm insertItem:msg_item atIndex:(i_msg)];
        i_msg++;
        //...
    }
}
```

How do I pass a parameter to `@selector(goToURL:)`, so that on item-click I could call:

```
+ (void)goToURL:(id)obj {
    NSLog(@"Open url:...%@", obj);
}
```

If I try passing `@selector(goToURL:var2:)` I get uncaught exception error.

Comment: Could you provide the actual code you are calling that is causing the crash?

Comment: added full function where I'm calling `action:@selector(goToURL:mid:)`... I also get 'Unused variable mid' warning in XCode... I am using it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have 2 parameters to an action method.  There should only be one, the sender, which in this case would be the menu item.  See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824287/how-do-i-set-the-sender-on-a-nsmenuitems-action) for a way to attach extra information to a menu item and retrieve it in the action method.